# WPF Designer exception while trying to edit UI in Visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008, data-binding, xaml

I have VS2008 with .net 3.5 SP1 installed on my machine, I have written one simple application with two listviews and databinding, My application compiles fine and I am able to run it, but when I try to open designer to edit controls,  I get following error.
I am not getting why this is happening. Any idea...see xaml below this error message

> Type 'MS.Internal.Permissions.UserInitiatedNavigationPermission' in Assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.SerializeObject(Object obj, MemoryStream stm)
>      at System.AppDomain.Serialize(Object o)
>      at System.AppDomain.MarshalObject(Object o)
>      at System.Threading.CompressedStack.GetDomainCompressedStack(SafeCompressedStackHandle compressedStack, Int32 index)
>      at System.Security.PermissionListSet.CreateCompressedState(CompressedStack cs, CompressedStack innerCS)
>      at System.Threading.CompressedStack.CompleteConstruction(CompressedStack innerCS)
>      at System.Threading.CompressedStack.GetCompressedStack(StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>      at System.Security.SecurityContext.Capture(ExecutionContext currThreadEC, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Capture(StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Capture()
>      at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
>      at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.RaiseRequerySuggested()
>      at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()
>      at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Interaction.Tool.TaskCollection.InsertItem(Int32 index, Task item)
>      at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
>      at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Interaction.SelectionTool..ctor()
>      at MS.Internal.Providers.VSActiveToolProvider.SelectionToolFactory.TryCreateTool[T](T& tool)
>      at MS.Internal.Host.ToolSubsystem.ActivateTool(ToolFactory toolFactory)
>      at MS.Internal.Host.ToolSubsystem..ctor(EditingContext editingContext, DesignerContext designerContext)
>      at MS.Internal.Host.Designer.Load()
>      at MS.Internal.Designer.VSDesigner.Load()
>      at MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedView.Load()
>      at MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedDesignerFactory.Load(IsolatedView view)
>      at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory factory, IsolatedView view)
>      at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory factory, IsolatedView view)
>      at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.Load()
>      at MS.Internal.Designer.DesignerPane.LoadDesignerView()

XAML :

```
<Grid Name="pngrid_Base" Height="auto" Width="auto" Background="Beige">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" MinWidth="221"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" MinWidth="1" MaxWidth="1"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Name="pngrid_BaseForAll" Grid.Column="0" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="#FFD8E4F8">
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="164*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="35*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="164*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="40*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView  Name="lstview_Unack" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,0,0,0" SelectionMode="Extended"  LostFocus="lstview_Unack_LostFocus" 
                                                                                                MouseRightButtonDown="lstview_Unack_MouseRightButtonDown">

            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,14,0,5" Name="btnFreeze">Freeze</Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,7,0,5" Name="btnAcknowledge" Width="96">Acknowledge</Button>
        <ListView  Name = "lstview_Ack" Grid.Row="3" Margin="2,1,0,0" LostFocus="lstview_Ack_LostFocus" SelectionMode="Extended" MouseRightButtonDown="lstview_Ack_MouseRightButtonDown">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />                            
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>


        <Button Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,12,0,7" Name="Clear" Width="78">Clear</Button>
    <TextBox Margin="110,6,32,5" Name="FilterText" TextChanged="FilterText_TextChanged" />
    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,5,0,4" Name="comboColumnList" Width="94" />
</Grid>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Name="gridSplitter1" Width="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Azure" />
    <Grid Name="pnGridForTreeView" Grid.Column="2" Width="200" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <my:TrinityDeviceTree  x:Name ="m_objDeviceTree" Height="auto" Width="auto">

        </my:TrinityDeviceTree>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: what could be reason for such error...it seems this error is very common but solution is not...have seen lot of posts with this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code inside VS2008 with .NET 3.5 SP1 and if i remove declaration for TrinityDeviceTree it works fine with the designer.
Maybe you should chek upon that UserControl and look there for errors. Also try to make a clean of your project and a rebuild, sometimes it works for visual designer's issues.